# How do I calculate the percent of the total per year when COUNT and WHERE is used?

Tags: sql, count, where-clause

In SQL Server, I have a query

```
SELECT season, COUNT(DISTINCT player_name) AS 'No. of Foreign Players'
FROM nbastats
WHERE country <> 'USA'
GROUP BY season
```

It return these results

| id | season | No. of Foreign Players |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1996-97 | 9 |
| 2 | 1997-98 | 14 |
| 3 | 1998-99 | 22 |
| 4 | 1999-00 | 24 |
| 5 | 2000-01 | 40 |
| 6 | 2001-02 | 51 |
| 7 | 2002-03 | 62 |

What I'm trying to do is to instead get the percentage of foreign players (over total players) each season.  The database only provides "country" so I assume I can only use

```
WHERE country <> 'USA'
```

and perhaps divide the total but I am unsure how to with WHERE in the way.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a ratio of a conditional:

```
SELECT season,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN country <> 'USA' THEN player_name END) * 1.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT player_name) AS foreign_ratio
FROM nbastats
GROUP BY season
```

Comment: Thank you so much!